# Arrange n Books When k Must Be Adjacent On A Shelf

Tags: combinatorics

There will be n Books, and k of them $(k \leq n)$ must be adjacent

How many ways there are, to arrange them on a shelf?

What I thought is that as for the k books there are $k!$ ways to arrange them.

and as for the other there are $\dbinom{n}{n-k}$ ways to arrange them.

so the sum is $\dbinom{n!}{k!}*k!=n!$

or is it just $(n-k)!*k!$  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the k books as a whole one big book then we have to arrange this $(n-k +1)$ books, and they can be arranged in $(n-k+1)!$ ways. Why$ (n-k+1)!?$ You just think and will get it. Then those k books can be arranged within themselves in $k!$ ways. So the answer is $(n-k+1)! \times k!$.

Answer (score 1):

There are k! ways of arranging the k books.  Treat the k books as a single unit when arranging them against the other (n-k) books so we have (n-k+1)! arrangements for each arrangement of the k books.

So we have $$N=k!\times(n-k+1)!$$